# How to convert a variable value to string in R?

Tags: string, r, variables

I have the following variable :

```
i="QW"
```

I would like to define the following vectore using i :

```
> c(QW=3)
QW 
3
```

However when I use

```
> c(i=3)
i 
3
```

It doesn't work, as you can see. So how to tell c() to use the **value** of i **instead of** using the **caracter** "i" to name the columns ?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you are confusing how indexing works.  `tst <- c("X", "Y", "QW", "Z"); txt[3]` reports back "QW"  So you can creat tst  and i on the fly and get answers back via `tst[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use `names`

```
i <- "QW"
dat <- c(3)
names(dat) <- i
```

Comment: That makes `dat` have value 3 and and name QW, rather than giving `QW` the value of 3

Comment: in one go, `setNames(c(3), "QW")`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setNames`:

```
setNames(3, i)
# QW 
#  3
```

Answer (score 1):

A way of giving `QW` the value of 3 would be

```
i  <- "QW"
eval(call("<-", as.name(i), 3) )
QW
```